# mount disk with password from applescript

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, script, mount, applescript

I'm using a applescript to mount my harddrive.

At the moment im using:

do shell script "diskutil mountDisk diskutil list | grep \"Harddrive\" | grep -o 'disk[0-9]*'"

Now i want to do the same but with a encrypted drive.

how can i fill te password in this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From StefanK at MacScripter:](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=122033#p122033)

```
property thePassword : "•••"
do shell script ("/bin/echo -n " & quoted form of thePassword & " | /usr/bin/hdiutil attach -stdinpass /Volumes/ExternalDisk/ImageName.dmg")
```

Comment: It seems that you accepted the answer, does this work for you now?